# Remove "Carpentry and woodworking" from the "Ask about" section of help page

Tags: discussion

I suspect it's leftover from before the woodworking site launched, but given that [woodworking](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com) does exist, the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) for this site shouldn't encourage users to post questions which would be more suited for another site.

On a related note, perhaps it would be helpful to point out other SE sites where questions that are off-topic here would be on-topic. For instance, [gardening & landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) for landscaping, [arts & crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) for hobby projects, etc.

[image: help page]

Comment: Looking at the edit history for the [tour], that text pre-dates the [help], i.e. it would have come from the old FAQ at [/faq](http://diy.stackexchange.com) which now redirects to the tour. Probably time we updated it.

Answer (score 9):

Per the usual division between them, Carpentry belongs here. Though "finish carpentry" starts to get fuzzy, and when you get to the point of built-in furnishings others fuzzier still. It's really more a matter of attitude and context than technique... but it's real, and it affects both where people will look and where they will find the best advice.

If it has to be permanently attached to the house to be stable, it probably belongs here no matter how pretty the woodwork. Putting poly on a flourishing improvement.

If it is just sitting on the floor, it probably belongs in Woodworking even if it's thrown together from white-wood dimensional lumber. Putting poly on a table is woodworking.

If it is hanging on French cleats, I can argue it either way...

Answer (score 2):

Ask about...

- Rough and finish carpentry.

---

Don't ask about...

- Decorating advice, [landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), [woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) or [hobby projects](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked [a woodworking question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/11632/10066), and got told to ask it on woodworking.SE (which is where the link points to now).

So, the removal the bullet in the FAQ saying that we can ask questions about woodworking **should really have already happened yesterday**.